# Websocket not working on GAE (Google App Engine)

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, websocket, stomp

I am using websocket in my spring boot + react application which was working fine ,Now i am deploying that application on GAE( it has four instance and can extend up to 6 instance).

But here websocket is not working fine as it should.

websocket connection is getting created but response is not coming from backend if i refresh the page then sometimes it works and if refresh again then it does't work.

Below is the Reference code to create websocket connection in React js :-

```
  @action connectToWebSocket = (channelName) => {
    this.webSocketInitilization();
    this.stompClient.connect({}, this.connectSocket, this.onError);
}

@action webSocketInitilization = () => {
      this.socket = new SockJS('/wss');
     this.stompClient = Stomp.over(this.socket);
     this.stompClient.debug = null
}

connectSocket = () => {
  this.subscription = this.stompClient.subscribe("/topic/model_" + this.modelId, this.onMessageReceived);
    console.log("connection created");
}
```

Backend configuration file :-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
 
    registry.addEndpoint("/wss").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");   // Enables a simple in-memory broker

}
```

}

Not sure what's the issue may be something related to GAE configuration ?

## Edited :- Adding app.yml file

```
runtime: java
env: flex

resources:
    memory_gb: 6.5
    cpu: 4
   disk_size_gb: 20
   automatic_scaling: 
   min_num_instances: 4 
   max_num_instances: 8
   cpu_utilization: 
   target_utilization: 0.6
handlers:
  - url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
network:
   session_affinity: true
```

I researched on that,so people was saying this parameter `session_affinity: true`  will work in `beta` version only, earlier i had another version so i updated my version but still this parameter is not getting reflected in my app engine config.

Regarding error logs :- Surprisingly i am not getting any error logs on browser console and not in GAE logs.

Any help ?

Comment: Could you provide an error message? There should be something in your GAE logs that can help us. Also it may be interesting to read [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity#session_affinity) about session affinity. If that doesn't work, attach the app.yaml file.

Comment: @Ajordat i edited my question.

Comment: Could you try running the sample from the example @Ajorda has provided, in order to locate how ws logs will appear and to detect when the ws connection gets closed and reconnect again? You could also try reducing the number of instances to 1 to check if the issue persists.